# C++11 compile fail, undefined reference, explicit template class instantiation inside another class

Tags: c++11, templates, compiler-errors

I tried searching through stackoverflow for this example but what I find doesn't address what I'm seeing.

I'm seeing the following compile error

> :(.text.startup+0x7): undefined reference to `fields::SECOND'

For this example code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

enum selector
{
    SELECTOR_ONE,
    SELECTOR_TWO,
};

template <selector E>
struct field_t
{
    size_t value;
    constexpr field_t(const size_t i):value(i){}
};

struct fields
{
    static constexpr field_t<selector::SELECTOR_ONE> FIRST{0};
    static constexpr field_t<selector::SELECTOR_TWO> SECOND{1};
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << fields::SECOND.value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I actually can make this compile by doing the following modification

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

enum selector
{
    SELECTOR_ONE,
    SELECTOR_TWO,
};

template <selector E>
struct field_t
{
    size_t value;
    constexpr field_t(const size_t i):value(i){}
};

template <selector E>
struct fields
{
    static constexpr field_t<E> FIRST{0};
    static constexpr field_t<E> SECOND{1};
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << fields<SELECTOR_TWO>::SECOND.value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm just a bit confused why the former fails to compile since that is actually what I was hoping to use default template class instantiations. Since I'm using C++11 the field_t class doesn't have external linkage (when instantiating a static constexpr field_t class) which is what putting in other fields class circumvents.

Comment: The error you cite cannot possibly be produced by the code you show. That code doesn't mention the name `LITTLE`

Comment: Can't seem to reproduce. Your example builds for me as written.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks I updated it to reflect the source. Here is where I was mocking this source w/this error http://cpp.sh/4dstm, let me know if the link works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I get past the linker issue by defining the fields outside of the "fields" struct. It's odd because using numerical values with static constexpr I never got this issue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

enum selector
{
    SELECTOR_ONE,
    SELECTOR_TWO,
};

template <selector E>
struct field_t
{
    size_t value;
    constexpr field_t(const size_t i):value(i){}
};

struct fields
{
    static constexpr field_t<selector::SELECTOR_ONE> FIRST{0};
    static constexpr field_t<selector::SELECTOR_TWO> SECOND{1};
};

// This fixes the compile error
constexpr field_t<selector::SELECTOR_ONE> fields::FIRST;
constexpr field_t<selector::SELECTOR_TWO> fields::SECOND;

int main()
{
    std::cout << fields::SECOND.value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```